# What is the best way to avoid being shot by snipers? (MW2)

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I always get frustrated when those stupid snipers start to camp somewhere where I cannot find them and they continuously shoot me. Often I try to find them to shoot them, but their one-shot kills don't let me. Sometimes I just get a Riot shield just to get closer to them >.<

What are the best ways to avoid being shot by snipers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, you should have a fairly good idea of the map layout. That way, you'll know what to expect, and from where. Learn common hiding places.

#### The Strategy

---

Stay out of his line of sight. Use available cover at all times. Don't just run around in the open. If you know there's a sniper nearby, take an alternate route and surprise him, or just avoid him entirely. Avoid choke points, as snipers usually cover those.

#### The Tactics

---

When a sniper is actively targeting you, ***move***. Take your shots at him if you have to, but do not stand still. You're asking to get shot in the head if you do. Move unpredictably and chaotically. Jump, run back and forth, anything that you think he isn't expecting. He won't miss if he can predict where you'll be, so you've got to make sure he can't do that.

In that situation I personally would figure a way to flee and flank him. If you don't have a sniper rifle, you're at a disadvantage at a distance.

Comment: You can also break out your One Man Army/Danger Close/Grenade Launcher class and spam them for being a camper...haha!

Comment: @DarkShiva - I'll have to test those out once I can create classes with those perks. :)

Answer (score 5):

Serpentine.

ie zig zag while you run.

A random crouch or jump wouldn't hurt either. Don't run in straight lines.

Comment: I've seen people perform super jumps...jumps that are impossible with regular gravity. How does work?

Comment: +!, Zig-zag from cover to cover, switching between crouching and standing (tactical layout) is hell for a sniper. Bouncing into random squats really screws them if they're trying to get headshots.